# Finding generating series

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, additive-combinatorics

I am not able to figure out this problem based on Combinatorics -

How many integer compositions of n, where $n ≥ 0$, are there where every part is even, and there are at least three parts?

How should we find the generating series?

Comment: so you mean like $2+4+6$ but not $2+3+7$?

Comment: "every part is even" means using $x^2$ rather than $x$

Comment: We will need to find a weight function

Comment: "a weight function"  I don't know what that means in this context.  You've seen how some generating series can be written using building blocks such as $(1+x+x^2+\dots)$ or $(\cdots)+(\cdots)^2+(\cdots)^3+\dots$ etc... right?  Just use the appropriate building blocks for this context.  In particular note how "only even parts" affects the variable used (*as alluded to earlier, use $x^2$ rather than $x$*) and how "at least three parts" affects where the sum starts.

Comment: Still not sure about that

Comment: Giving hints for this is difficult since it really is a one-step process and you should be able to just replace values in related examples, but here is a related example anyways. 
 $(\underbrace{1+x+x^4+x^5+\cdots}_{\text{available part sizes}})^{\overbrace{2}^{\text{number of parts}}}$ is the generating function for the number of partitions with exactly two parts and each part is of size $0,1,4,5,\dots$.  If we were to add another copy of this but change the exponent to $3$ instead, then it would be exactly two or three parts, etc...

Comment: Now... it is common to simplify things using geometric series, noting that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- The number of all compositions of $n$ into a positive number of positive parts is $2^{n-1}$ except when $n=0$ when it is $0$ (stars and bars can show this).  So find the generating function for this
- The number of compositions of $n$ into $1$ positive part is $1$ except when $n=0$ when it is $0$ (stars but no bar).  So find the generating function for this
- The number of compositions of $n$ into $2$ positive parts is $n-1$ except when $n=0$ when it is $0$ (stars and one bar).  So find the generating function for this
- So the generating function for the number of compositions of $n$ into $3$ or more positive parts is the first generating function above minus the second and the third
- To make sure "every part is even" involves replacing $x$ by $x^2$, so you can find the generating function for the number of compositions of $n$ into $3$ or more positive even parts

As a check, we have $8=2+2+2+2=4+2+2=2+4+2=2+2+4$, i.e. $4$ ways of making $8$, so see if your answer reproduces this for the coefficient of $x^8$ in its expansion

Comment: Incidentally, the same analysis says that the number of compositions of $n$ into $3$ or more positive parts is $2^{\frac n2 -1} -\frac n2$ when $n$ is a positive even number and is $0$ otherwise

Comment: I don't think that's a correct approach

Comment: @William: it does produce the correct generating function of $\frac{x^6}{(1-2x^2)(1-x^2)^2}$.  What approach would you suggest?